# Android CalendarView: Run activity when click selected date

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-date, calendarview

I am using a CalendarView to display a calendar, and I want to launch an activity when a specific date is clicked. I got it to work when a different date is clicked, but not when today's date is clicked. For example: Today is the 30th of January. My new activity launches when I click any other date on the calendar, but not when I click the 30th (unless I click another date, go back, then click the 30th).

I know this happens because I used the onSelectedDayChange() method, but I can't seem to find a working way to have the activity run when 'todays' date is clicked initially. I enabled android:clickable in my xml and I have android:onClick set to run a method but that never gets triggered. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: That's not really the role of `CalendarView`. It is designed to allow the user to choose a date as part of a larger piece of UI, not to take a specific action upon the clicking of a date.

Comment: What do you suggest I use to accomplish this?

Comment: I am not aware of any existing reusable component designed to handle your scenario.